# ORA-03297: the file contains the data used outside the value requested for RESIZE

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

there is a problem, I have a table space, it takes 6.6 gig. But it takes 400 MB. I want to reduce it to at least 2 gigs. But I have a problem "ORA-03297: the file contains the data used outside the value requested for RESIZE". Has anyone encountered such a problem ??

Comment: No, I haven't. `ALTER TABLESPACE mytable COALESCE;` may help, though. This should defrag the space. I don't know, though, whether it will move all the used space to the front of the whole space or just defrag parts of it. Well, just try.

Comment: I've just found some more information that may help here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_03297_file_contains_used_data_beyond_requested_resize_value.htm

Comment: Resizing a tablespace doesn't consolidate the content or relocate the high water mark for the content. You can't make the tablespace smaller than the location of the high water mark without reorganizing the individual objects. Often that means moving them to a different tablespace so that you can shrink the original, then moving them back.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks, but unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is *where* your data (segments) are located. Lets assume your file grows from "left to right", thus is starts like this: (dash = empty, X = used)

```
|-------------|
```

and then as you create tables, indexes etc, it becomes

```
|XXXXXXXX-----|
```

Once the file gets full, it will automatically extend to hold more data

```
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX--|
```

and so forth.  Now you drop some objects (eg truncate, drop a table, index etc). This leaves you some free holes in your file

```
|XXX---XX--XX-------XX---XXX--|
```

so now you have (say) 600M of *used* space in the file, but notice that there is a segment (table/index) near the end (right) of the file, ie

```
|XXX---XX--XX-------XX---XXX--|
                           ^
```

This is the smallest point to which you can shrink your file, because otherwise you're going to lose that data.  Thus the "largest" shrink you could do would be down to:

```
|XXX---XX--XX-------XX---XXX|
```

To overcome that, you need to *move* those segments so that they are not in the high point of the file. Typically if there is free space, we'll occupy if it possible, so if you did a series of

alter table T move
alter index I rebuild

the above segments might now look like this in the file:

```
|XXX-XXXX-XX-XXX------------|
```

and thus would then be able to resize the file by a greater amount.

Alternatively, create a new tablespace, move the objects into that and the drop the now empty old tablespace.